# How can I see what event handlers are set in js with firebug?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, firebug

A similar question answers how to do this in Chrome, but I have a bug I can reproduce intermittently in Firefox only.

Specifically, after this line executes (using the [hoverintent jquery plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)):

```
level1Items.hoverIntent(config)
```

Sometimes I get the expected behavior and sometimes I don't.  I think it's a race condition, but that's besides the point.  I just want to first check if the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are set, and if so, what they are set to.  Then I can test if the events are triggered as expected.

Comment: do you mean mouseover and mouseout events? there is no hover event in vanilla dom javascript, although some js librarys add it.

Answer (score 0):

by placing this url in your browsers location bar,

```
javascript:(function(){if(typeof%20VisualEvent!='undefined'){if(document.getElementById('Event_display')){VisualEvent.fnClose();}else{VisualEvent.fnInit();}}else{var%20n=document.createElement('script');n.setAttribute('language','JavaScript');n.setAttribute('src','http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/design/event/media/js/event-loader.js');document.body.appendChild(n);}})();
```

The javascript formatted looks like this:

```
(
    function(){
        if(typeof VisualEvent!='undefined') {
            if(document.getElementById('Event_display')){
                VisualEvent.fnClose();
            } else {
                VisualEvent.fnInit();
            }
        } else {
            var n=document.createElement('script');
            n.setAttribute('language','JavaScript');
            n.setAttribute('src','http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/design/event/media/js/event-loader.js');
            document.body.appendChild(n);
        }
    }
)();
```

Comment: Can you please go into detail about what this is doing exactly?

Comment: well a late comment but, this is an external javascript library

Comment: I understand that, but is there any, e.g., tutorial on using it or what it does in detail?  I'm a bit wary of just adding this js, and the js it imports, and the js _it_ imports.  I was looking for something more like a simple line or two of js to get the events.

Comment: just type console.log($("element").click); or other event to see which functie is associated with the element. you can see that by logging the whole element data too console.log($("#element").data());